# In-house app distribution error using Mobile-Iron: required CoreFoundation property is missing

Tags: ios, properties, core-foundation, in-house-distribution

I've build an in-house distribution version of my app which is already available in the AppStore. I was invited by the customers development team and code-signed the app as a customer development team member with their Distribution- and Development certificates.
I tested this customer-made version on my iPad, using iTunes and while the app started I've got a message on the iPad asking: "Do you want to run this app made for customer xx?".

I emailed this build-version to the customer, which they tried to distribute using MobileIron (see http://www.mobileiron.com). However during distribution they got, using MobileIron's Add-App-Wizard the following error message:

```
"Resource creation failed: Exception while saving apps. Cause: A Required CoreFoundation (CF) property is missing from the IPA file."
```

In the Apple Developer Library's article "Information Property List Key Reference: Core Foundation Keys" I couldn't find any clues on what particular property was meant above. Even the customer was not able (yet) to retrieve the specific CoreFoundation key which was missing.
Does anybody here have any suggestions on how to fix this? I'ld love to assign a 'Code-Heaven master badge' to the one who will come with the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had this issue and found the answer on the MobileIron support portal. MobileIron requires the following attributes to be set in Info.plist:
CFBundleName, CFBundleIdentifier, CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleExecutable, CFBundleVersion, CFBundleShortVersionString

In my case the ipa I was given was missing CFBundleDisplayName, which is apparently not set by recent versions of the AIR SDK.

Comment: That is correct; thanks for sharing this complete list. I also figured it out myself this afternoon. In my case I forgot to add the CFBundleDisplayName property to the Info.plist, which was already defined in my InfoPlist.strings file. Strange that the AppStore approval process doesn't complain or warn me about this.